# linearize bilinear quadratic objective terms

Tags: linear-programming, modeling, gurobi, linearization

I need to model a problem as a linear program. However my working solution contains a (bilinear) quadratic objective term:
$$
\sum x_i * y_i \\
x \in \{0,1\} \\
y \in \mathbb{R}^+
$$

The value of $y$ is calculated in a constraint like this:
$$
y = \sum\limits_{z \in Z} \sum\limits_{k \in K} f(z,k) 
$$

Therefore, I tried to move $x$ to the calculation of $y$ and remodel it to an indicator constraint for avoiding quadratic constraints:
$$
\begin{align}
x_i = 1 &\rightarrow y = \sum\limits_{z \in Z} \sum\limits_{k \in K} f(z,k) \\
x_i = 0 &\rightarrow y = 0
\end{align}
$$

This solutions eliminates quadratic objective terms. On the other side is the solution gap around 100% and my originale (quadratic) solution archive <1%.

How can I create a stronger formulation for this case?

**Edit:** Fixed typo of x in equation like mentioned in the comments.

**Update:** Based on the answer of Erwin Kalvelagen I linearized the quadratic constraint. The resulting performance of my model is not well and the gap is much higher in the same time like the quadratic constraint.
Since I understand from [this questions](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/8572/converting-quadratic-constrains-to-linear-constraint), it is a bilinear/quadratic constraint. What does this mean for my model exactly? Does this have a significant effect to scalability/performance of models in general? Is it possible to say from experience which solution should be preferred (quadratic or linearized (with bigM-Constraint (?)) version)?

Comment: You wrote $x\in(0,1)$, but did you instead mean $x_i\in\{0,1\}$?  Also, what other constraints involve $x$?

Comment: It's not clear why the value of $x$ should dictate the value of $y.$ It makes more sense to introduce a new variable $z_i$ to replace $x_i\times y_i$ in the objective and then constrain it so that $x_i=1\implies z_i=y_i$ and $x_i=0\implies z_i=0.$

Comment: @RobPratt: Correct I fixed it.

Comment: @Prubin: I just posted a very small snippet of my model, because I could limit my problem to this constraint. By introducing a new variable and constraint, do you mean something like Erwin Kalvelagen proposed?

Comment: What other constraints involve $x$? In particular, what prevents taking $x_i=0$ for all $i$?

Comment: There a several constraints including $x$ and making sure, that at least one $x_i = 1$. Is it helpful to add them to my example?

Comment: Yes, please add those constraints, which might lead to alternative linearization approaches.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking along the same lines as Erwin.

Answer (score 5):

If you know some good bounds, it may be worthwhile to try a formulation with just binary variables. E.g.:

$$\color{darkred}z = \color{darkred}x\cdot \color{darkred}y$$

with $\color{darkred}x \in \{0,1\}$ and $\color{darkred}y \in [0,\color{darkblue}U]$ can be written as:

$$\begin{aligned}& \color{darkred}z \le \color{darkred}x \cdot \color{darkblue}U \\ &\color{darkred}z \le \color{darkred}y\\ & \color{darkred}z \ge \color{darkred}y - \color{darkblue}U \cdot(1-\color{darkred}x)\end{aligned}$$

Sometimes that is faster than indicator constraints (especially if you can find a good, tight $\color{darkblue}U$). No guarantee. The real secret behind developing good integer programming models is just to try many things.

Comment: I did implement constraints like you mentioned. I am use to think about U as a bigM value. Right now I did not test a lot a values but my current values slow down my model significant. So is it just about choosing the correct value?

Comment: I choose some values based on this blogpost form prubin https://orinanobworld.blogspot.com/2011/07/perils-of-big-m.html and calculated for each case an individual value for U (or M) that is the smallest possible value. But the performance (or the gap) is stille not very well compared with the original quadratic constraint. Any better ideas?

Comment: Often, but not always, linear formulations are a bit better, especially after cranking up the cut generation.